# Where to plug the Firewall into the SFP or a normal port?

Tags: routing, switch, ethernet, sfp

I have a Cisco SG220 and a ZyXel USG20 firewall appliance.  I'm new to the SG220 and SFP ports in general.  Where is the optimal place to plug in the Firewall to the Switch. Normally I would just plug it into any port on the switch, but with the SFP I'm not sure. [image: Network Setup]

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter much. The Cisco switch is only a layer-2 switch. There may be reasons to pick a particular interface, but you haven't provided any information that could affect the interface choice.

Comment: Interface is 1Gb copper.  Sorry about that.

Comment: There is more to it than that. You show the physical network design, but you could have a logical design that is different, the interfaces could be different speeds, etc. If there are 100 Mbps interfaces, and your WAN is limited to 10 Mbps, then the WAN will be the limiting factor. If you have multiple VLANs, you will want the trunk link to the routing device to be a faster interface than the access interfaces if you are doing inter-VLAN routing. Etc. There is just a lot of information you don't detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USG20 supports 1Gbps so I would connect to SG220 over one of two GigabitEthernet Ports which are usually used for uplinks next to port 0/23 and 0/24. Unfortunately USG20 doesn't support LCAP/PaGP so you won't be able to create bundle for redundancy purposes. But to be honest as @Ron Maupin said doesn't matter where exactly you will connect more likely your limited factor will be WAN.

Comment: Looking up - LACP(Link Aggregation Control Protocol)  and PAgP(Port Aggregation Protocol ) - Got it thanks!!